# Reading two column data into a list, sorting alphabetically

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, sorting, search

I am required to import a list of extras (sauces to come with a meal) and their respective prices. With some code from the teacher I am able to read the file, put the extra name and price into a list and then display it showing that it has worked. The problem now comes when I have to sort the extras alphabetically so I am able to apply a binary search to it. I have tried everything with .sort and OrderBy etc. but nothing works.

My external text file with the data

> Hummus,0.75
>   Chili,0.50
>   Tabouli,1.25
>   Tzatziki,0.50

Public class for extra

```
Public Class extra
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Price As Decimal
End Class
```

This code imports the data and puts it into a list

```
Dim allExtras = From line In System.IO.File.ReadLines("C:\Users\ExtrasList.txt")
                Let Columns = line.Split(","c)
                Where Columns.Length = 2
                Let Price = Decimal.Parse(Columns(1).Trim())
                Let Name = Columns(0).Trim()
                Select New extra With {.Name = Name, .Price = Price}

Dim extraList As List(Of extra) = allExtras.ToList()
```

Displays the list

```
Console.WriteLine()
Console.WriteLine("Extra Name" & vbTab & "Price")
Console.WriteLine("-----------" & vbTab & "-----")
For Each extra In extraList
    Console.WriteLine(extra.Name & vbTab & vbTab & extra.Price)
Next
```

I just need to get the extras and their prices from a separate file into an array or list that can be sorted alphabetically so a user can search to see if an extra they want exists. I also need to be able to access the list so a user can choose and extra and then the required price will be added to the total price. Any help will be greatly appreciated as this part is preventing me from furthering at all. I don't mind if someone is able to help me sort the list with my existing code or shows me a much more efficient way to read the data from the file into a list, I just need some sort of solution.

Comment: In your code you not trying to sort or `OrderBy`. `OrderBy` should work. If you tried with `OrderBy` then what you mean by "it is not working"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Linq
. . . . . . 
' I think, this is cleaner way to load list
Dim eList as List(Of Extra) = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\ExtrasList.txt").
    Select(
        Function(l) 
            Dim a() As = l.Split(",".ToCharArray())
            Return New Extra With { .Name = a[0].Trim(), .Price = Decimal.Parse(a(1).Trim()) } 
         End Function).ToList()


......
' Check if extra exists. Optionally, you can use string comparison options
If (eList.Any(Function(i) String.Equals(i.Name, "The Name"))  Then

......
' get price of specific extra
Dim price As Decimal = eList.Single(Function(i) String.Equals(i.Name, "The Name")).Price
```

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient way for searching by name and getting price by name will be to put names and correspondent prices to the `Dictionary`

```
Dim sauces = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\ExtrasList.txt").
                  Select(Function(line) line.Split(",")).
                  ToDictionary(Function(pair) pair(0), Function(pair) pair(1))
```

Then you can use it

```
Dim price As String
If sauces.TryGetValue("Hummus", price) = True Then
    ' Use price
Else
    ' Show not found message
End If
```

For listing you can iterate through all value-key pairs

```
Dim orderedPairs = sauces.OrderBy(Function(pair) pair.Key)
For Each sauce As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In orderedPairs 
    Dim name = sauce.Key
    Dim price = sauce.Value
Next
```

I suggest create own class for sauce with appropriate types

```
Public Class Sauce
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Price As Decimal
End Class
```

Then you can simplify your reading method by introducing own method for converting line to the instance of `Sauce`

```
Public Function LineToSauce(line As String) As Sauce
    Dim pair As String() = line.Split(",")
    Return New Sauce With
    {
        .Name = pair(0),
        .Price = Decimal.Parse(pair(1))
    }
End Function

' Reading
Dim sauces = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\ExtrasList.txt").
                  Select(AddressOf LineToSauce).
                  ToDictionary(Function(sauce) sauce.Name)

' searching by name
Dim sauce As Sauce
If sauces.TryGetValue("Hummus", sauce) = True Then
    ' Use sauce.Price or sauce.Name
Else
    ' Show not found message
End If

' iterating and ordering
Dim orderedSauces = sauces.Values.OrderBy(Function(sauce) sauce.Name)
For Each sauce As orderedSauces
    Dim name = sauce.Name
    Dim price = sauce.Price
Next
```